# Magento 2 | Send email from observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, template, email

I am currently trying to send an email from an observer.

This is the code:

> /app/code/UO/CustomerAdressChange/Observer

```
if(!empty($isModified)) {
    //Liefer- oder Rechnungsadresse ist veraendert worden -> eMail schicken

    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $transportBuilder = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder');
    $storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();


    $transport = $transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('adress_change_template')
        ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId])
        ->setTemplateVars(
            [
                'store' => $storeManager->getStore(),
            ]
        )
        ->setFrom('general')
        // you can config general email address in Store -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses
        ->addTo('myemail@mail.com', 'Customer Name')
        ->getTransport();
    $transport->sendMessage();              }
```

This is causing an error sadly.

Is there any standard email template identifier which I can set here:

```
$transport = $transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('adress_change_template')
```

Any help is welcome.
Thanks!

Edit:

> /app/code/UO/CustomerAdressChange/etc/email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:Magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="adress_change_template" label="AdressChange" file="adresschange.html" type="html" module="UO__CustomerAdressChange" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

> /app/code/UO/CustomerAdressChange/view/frontend/email/adresschange.html

```
<div>

Das ist ein Test 

</div>
```

It seems like it doesn't find my email template?

Update: This line is causing an error:

```
$email = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email');


->setFrom($email, 'Service')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to comment instead of post, but this seems like my only way to contribute. Have you created a custom config.xml somehow in order to produce the desired email address?
The reason that line keeps failing, is because I imagine that the sender resolver keep hitting a roadblock.

```
function Setfrom()
  {
         $result = $this->_senderResolver->resolve($from);
         $this->message->setFrom($result['email'], $result['name']);
         return $this;
  }
```

resolve($sender,$scopeId = null)

Resolve sender information. The $sender can be a string to identify which sender to lookup in the config and return the name and email for. The $sender can be an array prefilled with the name and email key/value pairs.

so perhaps, it is because it is not written as

```
$from = array('email' => "xxxxx@xxx.xxx", 'name' => 'AnyName');  
->setFrom($from)
```

Comment: thanks that helped a lot! Now this is line is the problem:      ->getTransport();

Answer (score 1):

**key code of sending mail:**

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
class ClassName implements ObserverInterface
{
protected $storeManager;
protected $_transportBuilder;
protected $inlineTranslation;
public function __construct(StoreManagerInterface $smi,TransportBuilder $tb,StateInterface $si)
{        
    $this->storeManager=$smi;
    $this->_transportBuilder=$tb;
    $this->inlineTranslation=$si;
}
public function yourFunctionName()
{
       $templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        $templateVars = array(
            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
            'customer_name' => $cname,
            'message'   => 'We processed your order ID '.$orederid.'. We will contact you soon in mail for the acknowledgement if you not receive mail within 4 hours please get help from support@xxx.com'
        );
        $from = array('email' => "xxxxx@xxx.xxx", 'name' => 'AnyName');
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $to = array('xxxxx@xxx.xxx');
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('order_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->addTo($to)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
   } 
}
```

please note it setTemplateIdentifier('order_template') so you need to create order_template. for create email template refer this [link](https://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-transactional-email-programmatically-in-your-custom-module/)

Comment: is there a standard email template identifier which I can try?

Comment: yes try your email template

Comment: Please read my update above.

Comment: setTemplateIdentifier('adress_change_template'); try this code

Comment: it's not working unfortunately

Comment: any error show ?

Comment: the problem is this line: ->setFrom('bla@universum.de', 'general');  it is random email.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78790/discussion-between-l-klmn-and-prashant-patel).